# How do you write an <%if then%> statement to show one picture dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to have one image show for the header on the root page of a RoR site, and all the other pages will randomly show one of three other picture.  The problem is I don't know how to get this to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Using layouts, perhaps: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application layout you can define the default header like this:

```
<% if content_for?(:header) %>
<%=yield(:header)%>
<% else %>
<%=image_tag(files[rand(files.length)])%>
<% end %>
```

And in the view for your home page, you would override it using `content_for`:

```
<% content_for :header do %>
<%=image_tag 'home.jpg' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Usually you can test the controller and react accordingly. An easy way to encapsulate this is to use a helper:

```
<%= image_tag(header_image) %>
```

This could be implemented simply in ApplicationHelper:

```
def header_image
  case (params[:controller])
  when 'home'
    # Standard home page image
    '/images/home_image.jpg'
  else
    # Randomly chosen header image
    %w[ /images/x.jpg /images/y.jpg ].shuffle.first
  end
end
```

You might want to make a specific directory for your header images and then load that list in dynamically instead of having to specify them in your helper.

Comment: any reason you that you prefer `params[:controller]` over `contrller.controller_name`? I've always done the latter.

Comment: Isn't it better just to override `header_image` method in `HomeHelper`, than to put controller-dependent logic in application helper?

Comment: Good answer. If the images are likely to change, perhaps instead of the static array of image names, you can make it configuration with `YAML::load(File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/images.yml"))`

Comment: @Mladen, I'm leaning toward liking this answer better, if only because it keeps logic in erb to a minimum.

Comment: @Mark: My answer was simplified to emphasize the point of layouts and `content_for`. I would probably extract "get random image" logic to the helper too. Also, I don't like the idea of shuffling the array in order to get a random element.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<%- files = %w(banner-1.png banner-2.png banner-3.png) -%>
<%= image_tag (files[rand(files.length)] if request.url == root_url) || 'banner.png' %>
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer the first part of his question, which is how to show a static image on the home page, and rotate randomly only on the other pages. Also, this probably shouldn't be inline, but as part of a helper.

Comment: Sorry, just realized I missed first part and added. Just displayed code inline for readability.